# javascript ISO8601 3.5.2 Time Of Day (24-hour) datatype disconnected from calendar

Tags: javascript, iso8601

ISO 8601 3.5.2 distinguishes between date-time combined values and time-only values. Time-only values model the 24-hour clock of an indeterminate day not on the calendar. For Time-Only values, 24:00 is a valid value, to distinguish the end-of-the-day from the start-of-the-day (00:00).

Until explicitly attached to a day on the calendar, Time-Only values are simply a point on the segment of finite time that runs from 00:00 to 24:00.

What is the current ECMA standard with respect to Time-only values?
EDIT: Is there a proposed standard that address this?

Comment: [You can browser through the standard yourself for questions like this.](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *current* ECMA standard for JavaScript there is no time-only type.  There's just `Date`.

Comment: You are so fast, Pointy. Nice hat :-)

Comment: @Tim ha ha thanks - I can't find anything out there to suggest that anybody plans to add a time-only type, though it seems like a useful thing to have for some purposes.