# bootstrap-datetimepicker support of 24:00

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, iso, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a problem with https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker.
I have input as time picker to allow the user to select start and end times of a day.
I need to have an option to select between 00:00 to 24:00, but I can select only 23:59 as the last one.

If I'm correct it must be supported because of ISO8601 3.5.2 Time Of Day (24-hour).

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: When the time is 23:59:59 and the clock ticks over 1 second the time is usually 00:00:00 the next day. The notation 24:00 mainly serves to refer to the exact end of a day in a time interval.

Comment: The interval from 0:00:00 to 23:59:59.9999 equals exactly 24 hours

Comment: In some cases, for example when you need to show working hours, you had to setup 24:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should show the time as 24:00. Showing the time as 24:00 means its 00:00 next day. Why should we create such UI to confuse the user.

Also I think we sit down to make the plugin show 24:00 for today we have to come up with some logic to distinguish it from 00:00 for tomorrow.

Comment: Please see more details on ISO8601 3.5.2 Time Of Day (24-hour) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540759/javascript-iso8601-3-5-2-time-of-day-24-hour-datatype-disconnected-from-calend

Comment: Thank you for your link, but for my case it will be nice to have option of 24:00. My case is to show working hours, so e.g. bar may start work at 14:00 and ends at 24:00

Comment: Hmm got it. How about let the user pick date as 00:00 in the date picker, but when we display it over other places, replace 00:00 with 24:00

Comment: Most of users wants to have intuitively understandable UI so that 00:00 - means start of day and 24:00 means end of day.

Comment: I found such version https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker but I need timepicker for bootstrap

Comment: I went through the source code and found how its implemented. Then I head over to try and make similar changes to the required lib. Its large. I may take this as side project to implement `24:00` and raise a pull request, but I am sorry I can't do it right now.

Comment: thank you! I think it will be nice to have such option in future. Can you please add this as answer and provide possible estimate when it may be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the function below in "bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"

It wil now accept 24:00 :-)

```
change = function (e) {
    var val = $(e.target).val().trim(),
    parsedDate = val ? parseInputDate(val) : null;

    //Romke hack for 24:00
    if(val != '24:00') {
        setValue(parsedDate);
    }
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    return false; },
```